# With PHP is there an easy way to connect/execute queries against AS400 (like mysql)

Tags: php, ibm-midrange

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Connect PHP to an AS/400](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696/connect-php-to-an-as-400)

I need to connect to and execute queries against an AS400 (iseries)... is there an easy way to, with PHP, connect the same way you can connect with MySQL, i.e. connection string, database select, query and result with methods similar to mysql_query, mysql_fetch_assoc, etc.?

Thanks!

Comment: Please make sure that you edit your question and include all necessary details. People have flagged this as an exact duplicate, and it's likely to get closed if it isn't clear why it *isn't* a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what system php is running on linux or windows...

If its windows, I would think you'd need to set up an odbc type connection to the AS-400 and then query the odbc connection but I'm not 100% sure that php on windows supports that.

If its linux then you need to check out http://www.php.net/odbc for more information regarding the PHP side.

Comment: Sorry - PHP is running on a WAMP stack