# PHP on Windows -> AS400 is there an easy way?

Tags: php, odbc, ibm-midrange

Background:

- I am running PHP on a WAMP stack
- I need to connect/execute queries against an AS400 (IBM iSeries)

My Question:

Is there an easy way to, with PHP, connect the same way you can connect with MySQL, i.e. connection string, database select, query and result with methods similar to mysql_query, mysql_fetch_assoc, etc.?

This was marked as a duplicate yesterday, I apologize, it is not. I have not found a way to do it with windows online. Thanks!

MG

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/696/connect-php-to-an-as-400

Comment: Thanks alex, however, I'm asking about windows - that thread is regarding Linux.

Answer (score 2):

I am sure it was marked duplicate because the answer is the same. You can use ODBC to connect to the i.

Comment: unixODBC does not work for Windows. See PDO_ODBC support instead.